# Spiral of Theodorus - Discussion

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, irrational-numbers

The fact that $\sqrt2$ is not rational goes back to [Theodorus of Cyrene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodorus_of_Cyrene) from the school of Pythagoras, and is discussed in Plato's dialog "Theaetetus".

Of course, $\sqrt n$ is not rational for any square-free positive integer $n$.
However, the theorem was stated and proved by Theodorus of Cyrene only for $n<17$ unless $n=1,4,$ and $9$.

What are some plausible explanations of the obstacle which did not allow Theodorus of Cyrene to obtain this important theorem in full generality?

---

I thought that it's possibly because since he used the traditional Pythagorean method of odds and evens, $17$ is the first number for which this method breaks down.

Or maybe that the $\sqrt{17}$ adjacent leg belongs to the last triangle that does not overlap the figure, from the [Spiral of Theodorus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_Theodorus).

What are some other possible reasons why he stopped at $17$?

Comment: Isn't it plausible that he just got bored after doing all the previous cases, and stopped after 17? Maybe we also need to try to get into the frame of mind that people had 2000 years ago, when maybe generalisations were not so easy to write down and explain?

Comment: @PandaMan Clearly obvious that after $n=17$ the central angle at pole exceeds $360^0$. The plot becomes clumsy as the spiral overlaps on itself. After  having understood the tendency it serves no purpose to go any further with known monotone behavior.

Answer (score 2):

From the Wikipedia entry for Wilbur Knorr, on one of his books:

> *The Evolution of the Euclidean
>   Elements: A Study of the Theory of
>   Incommensurable Magnitudes and Its
>   Significance for Early Greek
>   Geometry* (Dordrecht: D. Reidel Publishing Co., 1975).
>
> This work incorporates Knorr's Ph.D.
>   thesis. It traces the early history of
>   irrational numbers from their first
>   discovery (in Thebes between 430 and
>   410 BC, Knorr speculates), through the
>   work of Theodorus of Cyrene, who
>   showed the irrationality of the square
>   roots of the integers up to 17, and
>   Theodorus' student Theaetetus, who
>   showed that all non-square integers
>   have irrational square roots. Knorr
>   reconstructs an argument based on
>   Pythagorean triples and parity that
>   matches the story in Plato's
>   Theaetetus of Theodorus' difficulties
>   with the number 17, and shows that
>   switching from parity to a different
>   dichotomy in terms of whether a number
>   is square or not was the key to
>   Theaetetus' success.

(Note:  This is copied from an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107153/first-known-proof-of-sqrt-2-is-irrational-with-prime-factorization) I gave at MathOverflow a year ago.)